# undefined reference to `initscr' with -lncurses

Tags: c, makefile, ncurses

I noticed my program doesn't build on another distro. I have -lncurses on makefile CFLAGS but get "undefined reference to `initscr'" errors.

Here is the makefile:

```
CFLAGS+=-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -lncurses
BIN=progname

all: $(BIN)

install: all
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin
    install -m 755 $(BIN) $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/

uninstall:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/$(BIN)

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)
```

Here is the cc command:

```
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -lncurses    nbwmon.c   -o nbwmon
```

If i move -lncurses last it builds fine:

```
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall    nbwmon.c   -o nbwmon -lncurses
```

So how can i fix this? How can i move -lncurses directive last on makefile?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the question is how to reorganize the makefile rather than why the gcc triggers "undefined reference"

Answer (score 1):

It's because the linker looks up dependencies in a kind of reverse order, so if object file O depends on library L, then the library L must be *after* the object file O in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Move `-lncurses` from `CFLAGS` into `LDFLAGS`:

```
CFLAGS+=-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
LDFLAGS+=-lncurses
```